# How to make an array of strings part of a react form to submit to prisma

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, prisma

I am trying to make an app with react, graphql, prisma, apollo and typescript.

I have a prisma model with:

```
model IssueGroup {
  id              String @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  title           String
  description     String
  issues          Issue[]
  categories      Category[]
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt       DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)
}


model Issue {
  id              String      @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  title           String
  description     String
  issueGroup      IssueGroup?  @relation(fields: [issueGroupId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull, onUpdate: Cascade)
  issueGroupId    String?      @db.Uuid
  subscribers     UserIssue[]
  categories      Category[]
  createdAt       DateTime    @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt       DateTime    @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)
}
```

I intend for issues to belong to issueGroups. Issues may or may not exist. Issues should be nullable in issueGroup - because there may not be any. I can't find a way to do either of setting issues to nullable in issueGroup, in the prisma model, or find a way to add them to the inputs so that I can actually add them in the form.

I have an api/inputs/create.input.ts file with:

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator"
import { Field, InputType } from "type-graphql"

import { IssueGroup } from "../issueGroup.model"

@InputType()
export class IssueGroupInput implements Partial<IssueGroup> {
  @Field()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  title: string

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field()
  description: string

  @Field()
// this is wrong but i can't figure out why
  issues: string[]

// this is wrong but it's also a guess so I don't know if it is close to what's required
  @Field(type => Issue)
  issues: string[]
}
```

the model has:

```
import * as Prisma from "@prisma/client"
import { Field, ObjectType } from "type-graphql"

import { BaseModel } from "../shared/base.model"

@ObjectType()
export class IssueGroup extends BaseModel implements Prisma.IssueGroup {
  @Field()
  title: string

  @Field()
  description: string

  @Field((type) => String)
  issues: Prisma.Issue[]
}
```

I am trying to make a form as follows:

```
import * as React from "react"
import {  CgTrash, CgEditMarkup } from "react-icons/cg"
import { VscIssues } from "react-icons/vsc"

import { gql } from "@apollo/client"
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  ButtonGroup,
  IconButton,
  useDisclosure,
  Wrap,
  Stack,
  Table,
  Tbody,
  Tr,
  Td,
  TableContainer,
  Text
} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import Head from "next/head"
import { useToast } from "lib/hooks/useToast"
import { useForm } from "lib/hooks/useForm"
import { Form } from "components/Form"
import { FormError } from "components/FormError"
import { Input } from "components/Input"
import { Textarea } from "components/Textarea"

import { 
    // IssueGroupInput, 
    useAllIssueGroupsQuery, 
    useCreateIssueGroupMutation, 
    useUpdateIssueGroupMutation,
    useDeleteIssueGroupMutation,  
    IssueGroup as IssueGroupGQLType,  
}  from "lib/graphql"
//
// import { AdminCreateIssueGroupForm } from "components/AdminCreateIssueGroupForm"
// import { AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm } from "components/AdminUpdateIssueGroupForm"
import { AdminLayout } from "components/AdminLayout"
import { AuthedHomeLayout } from "components/AuthedHomeLayout"
import { Modal } from "components/Modal"
import Yup from "lib/yup"

// import { PartialCheckIcon } from "components/PartialCheckIcon"
// import { Search } from "components/Search"
// import type { Sort } from "components/Table"
// import { Column, getOrderBy, Table } from "components/Table"

const __ = gql`

  mutation CreateIssueGroup($data: IssueGroupInput!) {
    createIssueGroup(data: $data) {
      id
      title
    }
  }  
  query AllIssueGroups {
    allIssueGroups {
      id
      title
    }
  }

  mutation updateIssueGroup($id: String!) {
    updateIssueGroup(id: $id) {
        id
        title
        issues
    }
  }

  mutation deleteIssueGroup($id: String!) {
    deleteIssueGroup(id: $id) {
      id
      title

    }
  }
`

const IssueGroupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required(),
    description: Yup.string().required(),
  })
  

function IssueGroups() {
  const toast = useToast()
  // const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("")
  // const [selectedIssueGroups, setSelectedIssueGroups] = React.useState<string[]>([])
  const modalProps = useDisclosure()
  const modalPropsUpdate = useDisclosure()
//   // const [sort, setSort] = React.useState<Sort>({ createdAt: SortOrder.Desc })
  const [createIssueGroup] = useCreateIssueGroupMutation()
  const [updateIssueGroup] = useUpdateIssueGroupMutation()
  const [deleteIssueGroup] = useDeleteIssueGroupMutation()
  const {  data: issueGroups } = useAllIssueGroupsQuery()
  const defaultValues = {
    title: "",
    description: "",
  }
  const form = useForm({ defaultValues, schema: IssueGroupSchema })
  const [selectedIssueGroup, setSelectedIssueGroup ] = React.useState<Omit<
  IssueGroupGQLType,
  "createdAt" | "updatedAt" 
> | null>(null)
```

// I tried adding | "issues" to the above list but my prisma thinks this cannot be null. I don't know how to direct it otherwise (so issues can be null inside IssueGroups)

```
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

    const onCreateSubmit = async (data: Yup.InferType<typeof IssueGroupSchema>) => {
        return await form.handler(
            () =>
            createIssueGroup({ variables: { data } }),
            {
                onSuccess: async (res, toast) => {
                    // await refetchAllIssueGroups()
                    toast({
                        title: "IssueGroup created",
                        status: "success",
                    })
                    form.reset()
                    onClose()
                }
            }
        )
    }

    const handleUpdateSubmit = async (data: Yup.InferType<typeof IssueGroupSchema>) => {
        console.log(selectedIssueGroup.id)
        return await form.handler(
           
            () =>
           
            updateIssueGroup({ variables: { 
                id: selectedIssueGroup.id, 
                issues: "none",
                data: { ...data } 
            } }),
        )
    }


    const onDeleteIssueGroup = async (id: string) => {
        return
        form.handler(
            () =>
                deleteIssueGroup({ variables: { id } }),
                {
                onSuccess: async () => {
                await fetch("api/issueGroups", { method: "delete"})
                toast({
                    title: "IssueGroup deleted",
                    status: "success",
                })
                },
                // refetchAllIssueGroups()
            },
        )
    }
  return (
    <Box>
     
      <Wrap mb={4} spacing={2}>
        <Button
          onClick={modalProps.onOpen}
         >
          Create issueGroup
        </Button>
      </Wrap>

      <Modal {...modalProps} title="Create IssueGroup">
        <Form {...form} onSubmit={onCreateSubmit}>
            <Stack>
                <Input name="title" label="Title" />

               
                <Textarea name="description" label="Describe" rows={4} />

                <FormError />
                <ButtonGroup>
                <Button onClick={modalProps.onClose}>Cancel</Button>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                >
                    Create
                </Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </Stack>
            </Form>
      </Modal>

        <TableContainer maxW="80%">
            <Table variant='simple'>
            <Tbody>
            {issueGroups?.allIssueGroups.map((issueGroup) => (
                <Tr key={issueGroup.id}>

                <Td>
                    <Text textStyle="h6">{issueGroup.title}</Text>

                </Td>
                <Td>
                    <ButtonGroup>
                    <IconButton
                        // onClick={modalPropsUpdate.onOpen}
                        onClick={() => {
                            setSelectedIssueGroup(issueGroup)
                            modalPropsUpdate.onOpen()
                        }}
                     />

                    {/* {
                        selectedIssueGroup && isOpen && 
                        <Modal issueGroup={selectedIssueGroup} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}  title="Edit IssueGroup"  >
                    } */}

                        <Modal {...modalPropsUpdate } title="Edit IssueGroup"  >

                            <Form {...form} onSubmit={handleUpdateSubmit}>
                                <Stack>
                                    <Input name="title" label="Title" />

                                    <Textarea name="description" label="Describe" rows={4} />

                                    <FormError />
                                    <ButtonGroup>
                                    <Button onClick={modalPropsUpdate.onClose}>Cancel</Button>
                                    <Button
                                        type="submit"
                                    >
                                        Save changes
                                    </Button>
                                    </ButtonGroup>
                                </Stack>
                            </Form>
                        </Modal>

                    <IconButton
                        onClick={() => onDeleteIssueGroup(issueGroup.id)}
                    />
                    </ButtonGroup>

                </Td>

                </Tr>
                ))}
            </Tbody>

            </Table>
        </TableContainer>

    </Box>
  )
}

IssueGroups.getLayout = (page: React.ReactNode) => <AuthedHomeLayout><AdminLayout>{page}</AdminLayout></AuthedHomeLayout>

export default IssueGroups
```

I have tried adding 'issues' to the gql in the update mutation of this form, and in the variables submitted when the form is submitted, but the error says that the value cannot be null.

Inside the form itself, VSCode says:

> Type '{ id: string; issues: string; data: { [x: string]: never; title:
> string; description: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Exact<{
> id: string; data: IssueGroupInput; }>'.   Object literal may only
> specify known properties, and 'issues' does not exist in type 'Exact<{
> id: string; data: IssueGroupInput; }>

I don't understand what this message means.

When I try to add issues: "" to the defaultValues setting in the form, I get an error that says:

> No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'issues'. Either
> declare one or provide an initializer.ts(18004)

I don't understand what this message is asking me to do.

When I try to interact with the object in the console, I get an error that says:

> message: 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field
> IssueGroup.issues.'